# Access a Spring Bean from JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Note:  See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45850435/put-a-spring-bean-into-the-application-scope) also.

I have a simple Spring Bean `myUrl` which is initialized with a URL (say `http://yourdomain.is.here/something`) from a Preferences location (Windows Registry):

```
<beans:bean id="myUrl" class="java.lang.String" >
    <beans:constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
        <beans:value>${my.registry.location:some.url}</beans:value>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

The bean works fine, but I want to use it directly in a JSP file which is included in multiple locations (hence, I don't want to try including it in a specific controller's model):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="myTags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<myTags:cssPath hostURL="${myUrl}"  relativePath="jquery-ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" />
<myTags:cssPath hostURL="${myUrl}"  relativePath="style.css" />
<myTags:cssPath hostURL="${myUrl}"  relativePath="tableSorter.css" />
```

So far, nothing I have tried makes the value of the `myUrl` bean show up in the `${myUrl}` expression.   I've gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234301/integrate-spring-beans-and-jsp-tags) and modified my `ViewResolver` to look like this:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/body/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <list>
            <value>myUrl</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

But still, the value doesn't show up.   I suspect I've forgotten something horribly basic, but I don't know what.   Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't you have to add the bean to the JSP context and <jsp:useBean>?  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm

Comment: can you try <c:out value="${myUrl}"/> and see what value is coming in the myUrl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a controller init method that gets the myUrl bean and stores it on the http session.

```
session.setAttribute("myUrl", myUrl);
```

Then in the JSP code you need to reference the bean.

```
<jsp:useBean id="myUrl" class="java.lang.String" scope="session"/>
```

For example to get the value:

```
<myTags:cssPath hostURL="<%= myUrl %>" ...
```

Comment: Seems like that's at least half the answer, but it would be nice to be able to do this from XML configuration without adding code to every controller - any ideas on the XML configuration?