# Put a spring bean into the Application scope?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

This is related [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847480/access-a-spring-bean-from-jsp):

I need to inject a Spring bean into the Tomcat application's scope at startup:

```
<beans:bean id="myUrl" class="java.lang.String" >
    <beans:constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
        <beans:value>${my.registry.location:some.url}</beans:value>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

Is there a slick way to do this from the Spring XML configuration or do I need to override some servlet method (ugh)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would post this in case it helps someone.   Spring has a bean that will do this on initialization for you:  [ServletContextAttributeExporter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextAttributeExporter.html).

You use it like this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="java.lang.String" >
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
        <value>${some.property.value}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
    <property name="attributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="myBean" value-ref="myBean" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can then do something like this in your non-Spring aware JSP code (for example):

```
<div>
    Value of my bean is:  ${applicationScope.myBean}    
</div>
```